# What's the principle inside this?

Tags: html

```
<a href="&#109;&#x61;... &#111;&#x6d;">&#x63;&#x74;... e&#115;&#x73;</a>
```

It's said to be the same as :

```
<a href="mailto:myaddress@mydomain.com'>contact</a>
```

But can work against email harvesting robot.

Answer (score 5):

They're numeric [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity), trying to trick spiders into not seeing "mailto" or characters in the form of an email address. And as an anti-harvesting strategy, it probably hasn't worked since 1997 or so. :-)

Comment: Hasn't worked because that most languages now have native functions like PHP's html_entity_decode() which does the match between those entities and the real characters.

Comment: @jpabluz: Exactly. The spiders interpret the entities and then scan the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

It assumes that spambot spiders treat webpages as text to regex match against instead of performing the most basic HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<a href="&#109;&#x61;... &#111;&#x6d;">&#x63;&#x74;... e&#115;&#x73;</a>
```

makes it a little difficult for email harvesting than its counter part:

```
<a href="mailto:myaddress@mydomain.com'>contact</a>
```

However, there are ways to decrypt even that so this is not that much useful in practice :(